# resize an image and keep it with new size

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I've an image with certain width and height values `<img id="image" width="500" height="100"/>`, and i want to resize this image to a new values and keep them with this changes infinite time.

i used `.effect()` function as this ..

```
$( document ).click(function() {
$( "#image" ).effect( "size", {
to: { width: 200, height: 60 }
}, 1000 );
});
```

but unfortunately seems that it's a limited time function, and the image return back to its original size.

A solution or helpful tutorial is great, thanks.

UPDATE:

A Fiddle about what happens with me: http://fiddle.jshell.net/SdHGK/

Comment: When does the image return to its original size?

Comment: directly after resizing is done

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with a demo of this?

Comment: when do u want it to resize? on a button click? And how do u want to resize it, by dragging it or only button numbers?

Comment: Initially just click any where, it resizes to the new values.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/SdHGK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this

```
$( document ).click(function() {
  $( "#toggle" ).effect( "size", {
    to: { width: 200, height: 60 }
  },'slow', function () {
      $("#toggle").css({'width':'200px', 'height': '60px'});
  });
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/SdHGK/2/

**PS:** The idea is taken from [Chanckjh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1303771/chanckjh) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18945386/829533) and from http://jqueryui.com/effect/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).click(function() {
  $( "#toggle" ).animate({ width: '200px', height: '60px'}, 1000 );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/8NdHU/

```
$('img').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css('width', '200%'); 
});
```

UPDATE

http://jsfiddle.net/8NdHU/1/

```
$('img').on('click', function(){
    $(this).animate({
        width: '100%'
    }, 5000); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using two class names for each size then on on click changing the class name.

```
function changeSize () {
var myId = document.getElementById("Your Id Goes Here");
myId.className="mySecondClassname";
}
```

You could also do it with Css3.

```
#yourImage {
    width:50px;
    height:200px;
    border:solid red 1px;
    transition:what you want to transition Duration; //probably width and height
}

    #yourImage:target {
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
}
```

You will need to add a "#" symbol to your image container that shows up in the url when it is clicked.